# share button under the post callback

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

we are posting the videos on the wall of user and the pages he has. we shares a link with og:tags the content gets render and flash works fine in page timeline. now we need to do is, we need to change some behavior if the video is shared from the page timeline the share button under the post along with the link and comment link,  we need to add an extra parameter to the sharing URL if user shares the video , 
and some call back so we can change in our database that the video link is shared
i had Google it but not founded any way around yet.

to see the behavior:

- Open:  https://www.facebook.com/SmashingSatellites/posts/761234327249785 or page url( https://www.facebook.com/SmashingSatellites)
- Hit share under the thumbnail.
- This URL http://www.littlecast.com/free_videos/fcb2df18-a597-43df-8c13-8f2f76e47b6b/wall_post?edit_id=0.5146727468697403&from_page_id=188020614571162&publisher=Smashing+Satellites will get share on your timeline
- what we need: need to add "shared=timeline" parameter to the above link.

screen short : https://fbcdn-dragon-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn1/t39.2087-6/851593_689592121098955_1268323226_n.jpg

Comment: Not possible to do that. The Share link is totally under Facebooks control and nothing you can change

Comment: hmmm , i have put the question of Facebook support, lets se if they can suggest something

Comment: :) great thank you. can we share a post by post_id using some javascript skd function?